Why does the file.type property return an empty string for a custom file extension with JSON content?
I am saving a file with a custom extension, let's say it's .abcd.
The content of the file is JSON.
When I write the file, I set its content type to application/json.
I can see this in the "content-type" field in the file properties after it's created.
So far, so good.
However, when I use this file in TypeScript with;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
and check the file's type parameter, I get an empty string "".
Anyone know what the problem might be?
(I don't want to change the extension of the file)
Thank!!

This isn't really a TypeScript question, it's a JavaScript question. You might want to edit the tags accordingly. From my brief look at the docs for the type property it says that browsers generally just look at the file extension to determine the type. So the behavior you're reporting is to be expected. Also, where is the "content-type" field in the file properties? Where is the file being written? A [mre] would help you get an answer more useful to you than just "change the file extension, or give up".

Thanks for the response!!
The file is created during a process in the application, saved in a cloud blob storage, then downloaded locally. Later I can load the file to a different part of the application (from my local device or with a path to the cloud storage).
The parameter content-type is shown on the file in the cloud. (specifically Azure)
is there a way to make JS/The browser set the type from the content-type and not the extension?

Most filesystems don't store MIME types explicitly. So applications use heuristics to get the type. The most common heuristic is inferring it from the extension; if you use a nonstandard extension, it doesn't know the corresponding type.
